# If I update the aliases of my existing index template, will the new aliases be present in the rolled over index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an existing index template and a rolling index that uses the template.
I have updated the aliases of the index template, after my rolling index is rolled over, will the new aliases from the index template apply to the newly rolled-over index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the new aliases that you have configured in your index templates will be used for the new rolled index.

However, all the previous rolled over indexes will not get those new aliases, you'll have to add them manually.

Comment: Cool thanks! Realised it doesn't apply to existing indices, but wasn't sure if it would apply to rolled over indices (in case the template used for roll over is cached or something along those lines)